# nytimes webpage new feature "More to Discover": how to block?

Tags: html, website, javascript, opera

How can I block the new feature on nytimes.com, which, when reading an article on their webpage, will scroll up a tab from the bottom of the browser window, called "More to Discover"? I've tried disabling Javascript and popups (via uBlock origin) but neither helped. Also, I've been unable to identify the source code controlling this feature in the "view source" option of Opera browser.

New feature:
[image: New feature]

Comment: uBlock Origin has an element picker. Also, “View source” is of very limited use on dynamic web pages. Use Developer Tools instead.

Comment: Thanks Daniel B- by playing around in Developer Tools, i was able to "delete element" on enough of the <script> sections to make that whole tab disappear. Is there any way to ... somehow automate this so i wouldn't have to manually do that every time i open a nytimes.com article to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know exactly which objects on the webpage you wish to suppress,
you may use the
[Tampermonkey addon](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/tampermonkey-beta/).

You will need to create "userscripts" that will delete these objects
from the webpage.

You will find more information about userscripts at the
[Tampermonkey home page](https://www.tampermonkey.net/index.php),
as well as on the original
[Greasemonkey website](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page)
(Tampermonkey is based on Greasemonkey).

Comment: There is need for an additional add-on besides uBlock Origin for almost all content blocking requirements.

Comment: I was just now able to read a nytimes.com article without that annoying banner popping up. I then scrolled through the article quickly, and the banner instantly DID pop up. I then scrolled through it again, slowly, and the banner did NOT pop up.


Could this nytimes.com webpage be detecting the speed of my mouse(trackpad) scrolling and only popping this banner when it detects that I'm just skimming the webpage?!?!?!?!??!?!?!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with AdBlock+. Go to "Customize" and block div with class="undefined css-1a1soaa"

```
nytimes.com##div[class="undefined css-1a1soaa"]
```

Since this solution may become dated, here was my algorithm

- Scroll to get "More to Discover"
- Right click a link and hit "Inspect" on Chrome
- Scroll up to find the class or some other identifying feature of the main banner

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Adblock Plus has a feature "Block element. Block specific element on this website." that appears in the drop down menu after clicking the ABP icon. Move the cursor over the annoying "More to discover" popup and it turns orange. Click on the highlighted region and select "Block". It's gone, at least on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Cory Smith's answer above worked for me -- but my Adblock (free version) worked a little differently. Here's what I did from chrome:

Click on the extension icon --> Options --> Advanced
then under Your Custom Filters, add the line from Cory: nytimes.com##div[class="undefined css-1a1soaa"]

thanks